# Tablet not connecting to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I have a D2-721 Android 4.1.1 Tablet. I have installed all the drivers for it. I have connected the tablet to my pc and everything is normal except eclipse. I can even Export my APK from Eclipse to my tablet but I cant run as android app from eclipse. My phone works fine. Eclipse sees the phone but not the Tablet. Is the problem my SDK? IS there something special I need to connect that kind of tablet to Eclipse? i have version 17 of Android SDK by the way

Comment: Have you enabled USB-debugging on your device?

Comment: I still cant get this to work. Don't buy D2-721 Tablet

Comment: @SmulianJulian which company's tablet is it?

Comment: The only information it gives is it's a D2 Pad. RockChip maybe? It says Rockchip system updates

Comment: Digital 2 is the company whoever that is. It was 80 bucks. Great Tablet for a 10 year old.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the  [OEM Drivers?](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)  and you need to install  the appropriate USB driver.
If already installed then need to update OEM driver

[image]

Comment: I have the Extras Google USB Driver

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled **USB-Debugging** on your device. It's step 2 as described here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

You need to do some magic to get it all enabled.

> On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in **Settings > Developer** options.
>
> Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, **Developer options** is hidden by default. To make it available, go to **Settings > About phone** and tap **Build number** seven times. Return to the previous screen to find **Developer options**.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with Nexus 7. Try this, connect the device, then swipe down your notifications on the status bar (left side), tap on `Connected as a media device` and change that to `Camera (PTP)`.

Comment: My Tablet doesnt have that option. When you connect all it says is USB connected and I turn on USB storage.